# Hangfire + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

This is my first time posting here.

I am currently writing an ASP.NET MVC application (using .NET 4.5.2 and MVC 5). I want to integrate Hangfire into my project. I have set up a side project which worked. But when I tried to integrate it into my main project, several errors occurred. They are:

1. The .dll files had to be strong-named (I fixed this issue by using ildasm/ilasm to strong name them. I replace the original files that came with the nuget package.)
2. After strong-naming and replacing the files, I ran into another error. When I tried to build and run the solution, a 'GlobalConfiguration' does not exists in the current context, and also a are you missing an assembly reference error is thrown.

I have tried various ways to solve this, but to no avail. I would really like some advice on this ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`GlobalConfiguration` is a class in the `Hangfire` namespace. You should import the namespace so that you can use it (and the extension methods it provides)

```
using Hangfire;
```

So now code like this will work:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("MyConnectionString");
```

Comment: Interestingly, this does not work for me, see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736118/how-to-configure-hangfire-with-asp-net-to-obtain-connection-string-from-config-f/

Comment: The 2nd command of yours is underlined in red in my VisualStudio, and I suppose it is due a conflict with `System.Web.Http`. I am struggling to reference the full name space `Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.[...]` or something.