# How to configure hangfire with ASP.NET to obtain connection string from config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dbcontext, hangfire

Please forgive me this probably stupid question, I am still not too familiar with the ASP.NET architecture in general.

I inherited a large project, and I intend to [setup hangfire.io](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/). I understand that I have to somehow initialize the DB context, but I do not want to hardcode it as suggested by the hangfire-docu.

My `API\Global.asax.cs` currently looks as follows, the interesting stuff begins after `// Hangfire stuff`:

```cs
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Hangfire;

namespace API
{
   public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
   {
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
          log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
          GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new GlobalExceptionLogger());
          GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
          MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
          AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
          GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
          FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
          RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
          MapperConfig.RegisterMapper();

          // Hangfire stuff  
          GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HardcodedContextString");
          RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("some-id", () => Console.WriteLine("My hangfire test."), "*/2 * * * 1-5"); 
       }
   }
}
```

My database context `myContext` seems to defined inside `API\connections.config` which contains the following lines:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=myContext;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**What shall I put instead of `HardcodedContextString` to make ASP.NET read the connection string from the respective configuration file?**

PS: Interestingly, both lines underneath `// Hangfire stuff` is underlined in red. What do I miss?

#### References

- [How do I set up 'connectionString' for a mySQL database for Hangfire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384732/how-do-i-set-up-connectionstring-for-a-mysql-database-for-hangfire)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134384/1236044 assuming your connections.config is included in your web.config
As to the red underlining it is because there is a conflict on GlobalConfiguration which exists in both System.Web.Http and Hangfire. Using the correct full namespace on use of GlobalConfiguration should solve this.

Comment: @jbl And am I correct about my assumption that `connections.config` contains my DB context? I am wondering since I do not see any connection string similar to the one in the docu.

Comment: No, `connections.config` just what it appears to be : a configuration file holding a connection string. That connection string is most probably the one which will is used to instantiate your `DbContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that `Hangfire` is actually installed (see also [Hangfire Installation Guide](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/installation.html)). For Visual Studio Professional 2017, you can do the following:

   1. Right-click on your project and click `Manage NuGet Packages`.
   2. Select **Packet source: `nuget.org`** on the right, search for `Hangfire` using the search bar on the top left.
   3. Select `Hangfire` and click **Install**. You might have to click on **Accept** when a popup-window appears.
2. Add `using System.Configuration;` in the header of `Global.asax.cs`. All following steps will happen within that file.
3. Define a variable which obtains the data base context definition from `connections.config`:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStringName"].ToString();
```

4. If you are using `System.Web.Http` like me, you have to replace all appearances of `GlobalConfiguration.xxx` with `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.xxx`. This is necessary to avoid a conflict since both packages have a (different) `GlobalConfiguration` property.
5. We also have to specify the full namespace for Hangfire. We will also use `connString` now: Instead of `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HardcodedContextString");` we 
   have to write

```
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(connString);
```

6. Everything should now compile without errors.

**PS:** From https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134384/1236044 I learned how to obtain the connection string from the config file-- thanks @[jbl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236044/jbl) for pointing me to that. JBL also gave me the hint about the name space conflict.